# Export csv returning a hexadecimal result

Tags: sql, powershell

When I try to run a result of a SQL query against Active Directory and export that to a CSV file I always get a hexadecimal result on each line instead of the properties I selected.

SQL:

```
$qry = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Name, IsCompliant,LatestEntry,ComputerManufacturerName,ComputerModelName,OperatingSystemName,MachinesUsersNames FROM ComplianceCore.MachinesComplianceView", $conn)
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $qry
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null
```

Powershell:

```
get-adcomputer -filter * -properties CN, CanonicalName, IPv4Address | Where-Object { ($_.Name -notin $dataset.tables.name -and $_.CanonicalName -notlike "*Domain Contr*" -and $_.CanonicalName -notlike "*servers*" -and $_.CanonicalName -notlike "*Idle Computers*") } | Select-object  CN, CanonicalName, IPv4Address | Export-Csv -Path "C:\BAC\WSUSScripts\MBAM Compliance\NotConfiguredResult.csv"
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You should show us some of the resulting file, however, you need to **remove** `| ft` as this is only for display purposes and can truncate the fiels values shown. Export the object(s) to csv as they really are,

Comment: @Theo Updated the result section

Comment: Did you remove the `| ft`, and what do you get when you execute `get-adcomputer -filter * -properties CN, CanonicalName, IPv4Address | Where-Object { ($_.Name -notin $dataset.tables.name -and $_.CanonicalName -notlike "*Domain Contr*" -and $_.CanonicalName -notlike "*servers*" -and $_.CanonicalName -notlike "*Idle Computers*") }`. What is in `$dataset.tables.name` ?

Comment: BTW. I would suggest using regex `-match` instead of these repeating `-notlike` comparisons: `$_.CanonicalName -notmatch "Domain Contr|servers|Idle Computers"`

Comment: Updated the FT, i use -notlike since I want to make sure I do not miss any spaces, And $dataset.tables.name contains names of devices which have bitlocker configured. My plan is to get all the devices in AD which are not in the $dataset.tables.name list

Comment: Does everything look correct if you skip the `Export-Csv` step and just output some of the data to screen?

Comment: @PMental yes it does something goes wrong with the conversion to CSV